# Javascript and regex for replace text with multiple

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace some words with regex.

For example:

```
var str ="hello world |bo hello world bo| hello world  |co hello world co| hello world,hello world |jp hello world hello world jp| "

var n=str.replace("world","stackoverflow");
```

But the content inside `|bo ... bo|`, `|co ... co|`, `|jp ... jp|` should not be modified world to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean to say that replacements cannot be done within those string pairs, kind of like "replace if not inside quotes?

Comment: I rephrased your question so that it is easier to understand ([this is the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10961486/1)). It seems like you want to replace `world` everywhere but not when it is inside these delimiters. That said, maybe *I* did not understand it correctly. If that is the case, please clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `/g` to indicate a global replace:

```
var n=str.replace(/world/g,"stackoverflow");
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dKU5/) to demonstrate.

**Additional Info**

Take a look at [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on RegEx flags.

Comment: no need to modify inside the  |bo ... bo|, |co ... co|, |jp ... jp|.But these regex will modify all the "world" to "stackoverflow".

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, it replaces "bb" with "xx" but not when "bb" is surrounded by "a".

```
t = "bb abba bb abba bb";
t = t.replace(/(?!a)bb(?!a)/g, "xx");
// t === "xx abba xx abba xx"
```